# What is the best way to make multiple connections at the same time?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm making a program that requires to make multiple connection on my website and keep it open for a few hours! So, let's say I want to make 300-500 connections and keep them up for 5 hours, if I use threads for each connection, how much CPU would it take approximately? Is there any alternative way to do this instead of using threads as it would take a lot of CPU?

Comment: What do you have control over? You need to be more explicit? Do you control the web server or not?

Comment: Do not use threads. Using threads for this problem is like hiring 500 secretaries to send 500 letters.

Comment: @EricLippert Yea, I understand. That's why I asked for an alternative solution, but I haven't found one yet...

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchronous sockets API.

Asynchronous Server Socket Example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

Asynchronous Client Socket Example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx

Using an Asynchronous Server Socket
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx

Comment: This is server/client example, but my website is already hosted, I can't make any change on it atm. How would I use this?

Comment: Are you writing the server or the webapp (using another server, such as IIS or Apache)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Apache. And the website is in PHP.

Comment: In that case, ignore this answer, and every other answer you were given. Mention in your question that you are using Apache/PHP. And tag it Apache + PHP, not c# and multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

[WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) is one option. Another is to consider using a network library which gives you the option of using either threads or asynchronous connections, [NetworkComms.Net](http://www.networkcomms.net) or [lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/).

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for NetworkComms.Net.

Answer (score -2):

HTTP as an application message protocol doesn't keep a flow back-and-forth of messages, but only a single pair is exchanged; a request and a response, and so from an application perspective it is a connectionless protocol. The connection-oriented TCP part is only to garantuee successful delivery of all data in the request or all data in the response.

As such it doesn't make sense to talk about keeping HTTP connections open from the server. The server might do chunked encoding to pretend it can send multiple reply messages, but that won't work empirically.

Comment: I have updated the text in response to your comment. I am not talking in vocab of TCP, but from an application protocol perspective. I hope the edit improved what I try to say.